# How to build a recommender engine from scratch ?

Tags: recommendation-engine, data-science

Hi i want to learn how to build a recommender system is there any good books or courses ? i already know about the theory i want to practice ( which langage or framework ) but i dont know where to go ! thanks in advance

Comment: down vote
I don't think this is the place for such a question, just because it's not answerable by code and will create general discussion based on opinions.

Comment: Agree, this question will be closed as either requesting opinions or requesting off-site resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the place for such a question, just because it's not answerable by code and will create general discussion based on opinions.

### BUT:

- I'd browse [GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=recommender&type=), [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=recommender&group_id=&project_id=&repository_ref=) or others for Recommender systems implementations.
- I recommend taking a look at this [list](https://github.com/grahamjenson/list_of_recommender_systems), There's a book at the bottom of this list you might want to check out.
- I'd recommend [professor Ng's course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning?utm_source=gg&utm_medium=sem&campaignid=685340575&adgroupid=32639001341&device=c&keyword=coursera%20machine%20learning&matchtype=p&network=g&devicemodel=&adpostion=1t1&creativeid=176442054671&hide_mobile_promo&gclid=Cj0KEQjwy4zLBRCOg6-4h6vs3cUBEiQAN-yzfohhVvcSqFlKsZKNocGdAL1c40JpbN3jE3McVuhOPXAaAv8c8P8HAQ). Week 9 deals with Recommender systems. That's entry level ML, but it's the course that stands out in my memory.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i didnt know that my post was inappropriate thanks again !